# Call NewObject method jni with params in jobjectarray

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am working in JNI with c++ and I have created a method where a series of parameters are passed to my native method as a jobjectarray.  I would like to call a constructor in JNI using those parameters.  However the NewObject method does not accept a jobject array instead using an ellipsis.  How would I accomplish this task?  I do not know how many parameters the constructor will be taking before the method is called and the signature string is passed along as well from java.  The constructor that I am calling does not take an array as an argument, instead different versions of the same class can be passed to the c++ function with each one containing a different method signature. I need my c++ method to generically be able to create any object with its passed arguments.  I am using visual studio as my IDE.  I understand I might need an array of jvalues but I don't understand how to get that from a jobjectarray.

Comment: Have you considered using multiple arguments, instead of just one array? That would make it much easier.

Comment: "call a constructor":  you mean a java constructor ? And how do you find the appropriate constructor, looking fo rthe appropriate signature ?

Comment: I don't know how many arguments the constructor will take before the method is called.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but for calling a constructor you first need to find it with `env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", signature-string)`. So you need to know the number of arguments in your array and their type in order to be able to find the right constructor.

Comment: I am passing the signature string from java where I it generate within a java method

Comment: Why? You can do everything you've described directly in Java using reflection. You don't need JNI for this.

Comment: I am trying to dynamically create an enum instance which is blocked by java reflection

Comment: In that case you don't even need reflection, let alone JNI. You just call the enum's static `valueOf()` method wih the string name of the enum. The enum itself is already constructed, by definition.

Comment: I have a class which takes an enum value in its constructor.  I need to create a new instance of that class using different variables than any of the current enum values currently hold.  I don't have code access to the enum or class to add a new enum constant so instead I have to construct an enum constant at runtime.

Comment: @popgalop This is basically illegal. Even if you succeed, the result won't be a first-class member of the enum class: for example, `valueOf()` won't work. I suggest you have an XY problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question. You can achieve this by using the other two ways that JNI API provides for creating objects (from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)):

```
jobject NewObjectA(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
jmethodID methodID, const jvalue *args);

jobject NewObjectV(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
jmethodID methodID, va_list args);
```

**NewObjectA**

> Programmers place all arguments that are to be passed to the constructor in an args array of jvalues that immediately follows the methodID argument. NewObjectA() accepts the arguments in this array, and, in turn, passes them to the Java method that the programmer wishes to invoke.

**NewObjectV**

> Programmers place all arguments that are to be passed to the constructor in an args argument of type va_list that immediately follows the methodID argument. NewObjectV() accepts these arguments, and, in turn, passes them to the Java method that the programmer wishes to invoke.

So, I made a sample program that shows how to use it.

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {

    private int bar;
    private String baaz;

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this(bar, "");
    }

    public Foo(int bar, String baaz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baaz = baaz;
    }

    public void method1() {
        this.bar++;

        System.out.println(bar);
        System.out.println(baaz);
    }
}
```

**Bar.java**

```
public class Bar {

    public Bar() {
    }

    public static native Foo createFoo(String signature, Object ... params);
}
```

**Bar.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Bar */

#ifndef _Included_Bar
#define _Included_Bar
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Bar
 * Method:    createFoo
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)LFoo;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Bar_createFoo
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jobjectArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**Bar.c**

```
#include "Bar.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

jobject JNICALL Java_Bar_createFoo
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass class, jstring signature, jobjectArray params) {

    // method signature in char *
    const char * signatureChar = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, signature, 0);

    jvalue * args;
    int i, size;

    // retrieve foo class
    jclass fooClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "LFoo;");

    // retrieve foo construtor
    jmethodID fooConstructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, fooClass, "<init>", signatureChar);

    // operate over params
    // ...

    // TODO: find out a way to retrieve size from constructor
    size = 2;

    args = malloc(size * sizeof(jvalue));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        args[i].l = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, params, i);
    }

    return (*env)->NewObjectA(env, fooClass, fooConstructor, args);
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME_HERE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = Bar.createFoo("(ILjava/lang/String;)V", -12312141, "foo");

        System.out.println(foo);

        foo.method1();

        foo = Bar.createFoo("(I)V", -12312141, "foo");

        System.out.println(foo);

        foo.method1();

        foo = Bar.createFoo("(I)V", -12312141);

        System.out.println(foo);

        foo.method1();
    }
}
```

Warning: it is still not 100% funciontal because I couldn't figure out how to retrieve constructor argument size based on constructor signature.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am trying to do.  The constructor that I am calling does not take an array as an argument.  The problem is that different versions of the same class can be passed to the c++ function with each one containing a different method signature.  I need my c++ method to generically be able to create any object with its passed arguments.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky because you've been passed a `jobjectArray`. This means that primitive types have been boxed (e.g. `int`s are `java.lang.Integer` instances in your array), and you have to unbox them before passing them onto a constructor.

What you're going to have to do is parse the method signature string (it's not nearly as bad as you might think), walk over every `jobject` in your array and convert it to the corresponding type (using an unboxing conversion if necessary).

Sadly, there's no built-in way in JNI to perform unboxing, and thus you're going to have to do it manually by invoking the appropriate methods of the boxed values (e.g. `Integer.intValue` to get `int`s).

The basic idea:

```
jobject createObject(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jmethodID constructor, const char *argstr, jobjectArray *args) {
    int n = env->GetArrayLength(args);
    jvalue *values = new jvalue[n];
    const char *argptr = argstr;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        jobject arg = env->GetObjectArrayElement(args, i);
        if(*argptr == 'B') { /* byte */
            values[i].b = object_to_byte(arg);
        }
        /* cases for all of the other primitive types...*/
        else if(*argptr == '[') { /* array */
            while(*argptr == '[') argptr++;
            if(*argptr == 'L')
                while(*argptr != ';') argptr++;
            values[i].l = arg;
        } else if(*argptr == 'L') { /* object */
            while(*argptr != ';') argptr++;
            values[i].l = arg;
        }
        argptr++;
        env->DeleteLocalRef(arg);
    }
    return env->NewObjectA(clazz, methodID, values);
}
```

`object_to_byte` and other conversion functions will be defined as functions which unbox the relevant type (e.g. `object_to_byte` will use the JNI to call `java.lang.Byte.byteValue` on the given object).

Comment: How is there no JNI method to do this automatically? If you make a native method a varargs method, the last parameter is a `jobjectArray`, and it must be unboxed before those params can be used to invoke another method that takes only unboxed params. This is such a common need that I don't understand how on earth there is no JNI call for this.

Comment: @LukeHutchison: Thanks for the comment! It turns out that there is in fact a better way to do this by going through the Reflection API - so I posted a new answer with this approach. I'm leaving this other answer up in case the reflection API can't be used, and in case people are curious about how to do this the hard way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LukeHutchinson's prompting, I went looking for a better solution, and am happy to report that there is in fact a simpler approach using the Reflection API. You can use the JNI function `ToReflectedMethod` to convert a `methodID` to `java.lang.reflect.Method` or `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`, after which you can call `invoke` or `newInstance` respectively, which will handle all of the necessary unboxing conversions.

Here's a proof of concept, with error checking omitted for clarity.

`test.java`:

```java
public class test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* This is the constructor String(byte[], int, int).
           This call will print out BCD - the result of creating
           a string from bytes 1-3 of the array */
        System.out.println(new test().makeObject("java/lang/String", "([BII)V", new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45 }, 1, 3));
    }

    private native Object makeObject(String clazz, String signature, Object... args);
}
```

`libnative.c`:

```c
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_makeObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jstring clazzName, jstring signature, jobjectArray args) {
    const char *clazzNameStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, clazzName, NULL);
    const char *signatureStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, signature, NULL);

    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, clazzNameStr);
    jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", signatureStr);
    jobject reflectedMethod = (*env)->ToReflectedMethod(env, clazz, methodID, JNI_FALSE);

    jclass constructorClazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/reflect/Constructor");
    jmethodID newInstanceMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, constructorClazz, "newInstance", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    jobject result = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, reflectedMethod, newInstanceMethod, args);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, clazzName, clazzNameStr);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, signature, signatureStr);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Now if only the JDK team weren't enforcing encapsulation as of JDK 16! (These reflection calls enforce access checks.) I really wish they would just add a `CallObjectMethodX` function to the JNI API that would take a `jobjectArray` in the last parameter position. Why the heck didn't they think to include that, when even native methods can take varargs (`Object[]` parameters in the last position)?